# Run rails application without using rails console or run rails application directly from Batch file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-file, console

I am working on Ruby on Rails application. For some reason I want to start my application from a batch file. Using the bat file I successfully run rails server and rails console. But I can't send the command from my batch file to rails console to start the application itself. Is there possibility to run rails console from batch file with key (something like: rails c & 'key running application') or is there any possibility to start the application directly from batch file without starting rails console?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In batch file write:

```
call rails c %*
```

or

```
call rails s %*
```

Anything you pass to batch file will be forwarded to rails commands. e.g.

`start_console.bat foo bar`, will results in `rails c foo bar`